# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to use BlueImp's FileUpload plugin, in a backbone.js view.  This was originally in the parent view, but I am trying to move it into a child view.  I have a designated hot spot that, when clicked, pops open the File Open dialog.  After a user selects a file and clicks ok, this error pops and breaks the code.  This is what I have:

Template:

```
<form id="fileManagementUpload">
    <div id="fileDropZone-cover"  name="fileDropZone-cover"  class="fileDropZone-cover-hidden">
        <div id="fileDropZone-center"  name="fileDropZone-center" class = "fileDropZone-center" >
            <div style="float: right; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">
                <button id ="buttonCloseFileUpload" class = "buttonCloseFileUpload"  style="border:1px solid #000000; color:red; background: transparent" type="button">X</button>
            </div>
            <input type="file" id="fileManagementFileUpload" name="fileManagementFileUpload" multiple style="visibility: hidden;" />
            <div><div style=""><h1>Drop Files Here</h1></div>   <div style=""><button name='fmFileUpload' id ='fmFileUpload' style="" type="button">Start Upload</button></div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Parent View (gets called in PostRender event.  ):

```
 initializeFileUploader: function(){
     //newFileUploader  is declared as a global property of the view, 
     //so it can be accessed anywhere
     newFileUploader = new fileUploader({parent: that});
     newFileUploader.render()

     that.$el.append(newFileUploader.$el);
     newFileUploader.createUploadPane();
},

//this function is called when the div is clicked, to simulate the File 
//form click
openDialog: function(e){       
        $('#fileManagementFileUpload').click();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();    
 },
```

Child View:
    Render:

```
 var template =   window.app.getTemplate('Template');
 var html = $(template({}));
 this.$el.append(html);
```

//.....

```
 createUploadPane:function(){
       var that = this;      
       that.$el.find('#fileManagementFileUpload').fileupload({
            dropZone: that.$el.find('#fileDropZone-center'),
            autoUpload: true,
            dataType: "text",
            add: function (e, data) {
            //....
            },

       });
```

The error occurs after the user selects a file and clicks open.  The error is within JQuery.  I can see that there is some kind of loop occurring, filling up the stack, but I don't know what would be causing it.  My code has now loop, that I can see.

**ERRORS:**

```
Sizzle.contains @   jquery-2.1.1.js?p:1407
jQuery.extend.clone @   jquery-2.1.1.js?p:5020
(anonymous function)    @   jquery-2.1.1.js?p:5271
(anonymous function)    @   jquery-2.1.1.js?p:144
jQuery.extend.map   @   jquery-2.1.1.js?p:468
jQuery.fn.jQuery.map    @   jquery-2.1.1.js?p:143
jQuery.fn.extend.clone  @   jquery-2.1.1.js?p:5270
$.widget._replaceFileInput  @   jquery.fileupload.js?p:1045
(anonymous function)    @   jquery-ui.js?p:401
(anonymous function)    @   jquery.fileupload.js?p:1218
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with :that.$el.find('#fileManagementFileUpload').fileupload({

If i change the name, the error doesn't occur but then the plugin doesn't work either.  Should I be attaching the plugin to the file control or the form?

Comment: Can you provide the top 10-ish lines of the stack trace shown in the error?

Comment: @ Peter Wagner, I added the errors that are shown.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: The stack seems to be getting in a loop in file jquery.fileupload.js on line 1218 (the _onChange function at:

if (that.options.replaceFileInput) {
                    that._replaceFileInput(data);
                }

Comment: Also, I use to have all of this in one view and it worked fine.  It was only after moving fileupload into its own, child, view that this issue arose.  I feel like it might have something to do with how the child view is added and how the plugin tries to attach to the file control.